# I need to pass a parameter from Parent to Child

Tags: c#, blazor

Ok, so I have a schedule page that I access using the URL localhost/{RoomId} where {RoomId} for now is an int (1, 2, 3 etc.) so this is the first line of this page:

```
@page "/roomzfront/{RoomId:int}"
```

This works to get the corresponding data from the database, but the actual booking function is placed in a child component and when I try to pass this parameter using:

```
    @functions { int PresentRoom = RoomId; }
```

I get the error 'a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field...'

However, using the code (Parent):

```
@functions { int PresentRoom = 1; }
```

and this code (Child):

```
    [CascadingParameter(Name="PresentRoomId")] protected int PresentRoom { get; set; }
```

doesn't pass the value anyway. ( [Got the tip here:](https://www.webassemblyman.com/blazor/blazorcascadingvaluesparameters.html))

Comment: `@functions` ?? That was abandoned 6 moths ago.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. Have googled like 50 different pages about Blazor and none mentions this. The code however seems legit in the @code section aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving the room ID in the page model (@Model) then you can easily access the room ID in the page using e.g. @Model.RoomId

Have a look at the following link:
https://chsakell.com/2013/05/02/4-basic-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

Data binding solved my problem. A good explanation is found here [Data binding](https://chrissainty.com/a-detailed-look-at-data-binding-in-blazor/)

In Parent:

```
<Child.Component TRoomId="RoomId"></Child.Component>

@code {
private int RoomId{ get; set; };
```

}

In Child:

```
<div>Room Id from Room: @TRoomId</div>

@code{
[Parameter] public int TRoomId {get; set;}
```

}